# Powershell read csv file, reformat into multiple lines, write to a csv file

Tags: powershell

Very new to powershell.  I want to create a powershell script that will read a csv file with lines that look like this:

```
6120137650,6/22/2020,,304066,267.98,,6/26/2020
6120208098,6/22/2020,,304329,230.54,,6/26/2020
```

Then create a new csv file that has three lines for each of the input lines, that look like this.  Anything added to the lines that was not in the input is constant.

```
*,CHR00,6120137650,6/22/2020,,304066,30,267.98,,6/26/2020
CHR00,6120137650,2001-00,P,-267.98
CHR00,6120137650,FRT OUT,R,267.98
*,CHR00,6120208098,6/22/2020,,304329,30,230.54,,6/26/2020
CHR00,6120208098,2001-00,P,-230.54
CHR00,6120208098,FRT OUT,R,230.54
```

So for each input line:

1. Write an output line that adds *,CHR00, then everything from the input line.
2. Write an output line with CHR00 followed by field 1 of input line, followed by 2001-00, followed by P, followed by field negative of field 5 of input line.
3. Write an output line with CHR00 followed by field 1 of input line, followed by FRT OUT, folowed by R, folwed by field 5 of input line.

Comment: What are the headers for each column?

Comment: The desired output will not be a valid CSV file I'm afraid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want an outputfile that is not a true CSV file, I think in this case you could simply iterate over the lines in the input file and output the newly constructed lines like this:

```
$inputFile  = 'D:\Test\input.csv'
$outputFile = 'D:\Test\output.txt'

Get-Content -Path $inputFile | ForEach-Object {
    # output the original line with '*,CHR00,' prepended
    "*,CHR00,$_"
    $fields = $_ -split ','

    # output second line
    $num = -[double]$fields[4]
    'CHR00,{0},2001-00,P,{1}' -f $fields[0], $num.ToString("F2", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

    # output third line
    'CHR00,{0},FRT OUT,R,{1}' -f $fields[0], $fields[4]
} | Set-Content -Path $outputFile
```

<sup>`-f` is the PowerShell [Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#format-operator--f)</sup>

Comment: My apologies for delaying in accepting this answer.  It worked like a charm!  Thank you!